# Navigate to composable without adding it to backstack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm using a [Compose Destinations](https://composedestinations.rafaelcosta.xyz) library and I don't understand what should I do to avoid adding destination to backstack.

Explanation: User navigates Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3, then he navigates back (by pressing button or back gesture) and gets into Screen1, because Screen2 isn't in a back stack. Screen1 <- ... <- Screen3

I searched for something like this in documentation:

```
navigator.navigate(SecondScreenDestination) {
    addToBackStack = false
}
```

But there are nothing like this!

I tried to use popUp functions to achieve my goal, but I didn't find the solution. I really need help with this.

Comment: What does "avoid adding destination to the back stack" mean? Any destination that is displayed is part of the stack (the one being displayed is the one at the top of the stack). Are you trying to say when your stack is `[FirstScreen]` before you navigate, you want it to be just `[SecondScreen]` and not `[FirstScreen, SecondScreen]`?

Comment: By calling `navigate(...)` you are telling the navigator to add it to the backstack. If you just want to display a composable without it being added to the backstack then just show it as part of the composition of your current screen. What behavior would you like to keep, and what behavior would you like to skip, by trying to navigate and not adding it to the backstack? Please give us some examples of how would you like to navigate between destinations in your app and what would you like that the back button (or gesture) does in each case. Explain what behavior you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I need to make one of my screens unreachable by pressing "back button". Is there another way to achieve that instead of way I proposed?

Comment: I'm afraid it still isn't clear what you're asking. Are you trying to say that when you are on `[FirstScreen, SecondScreen]`, you want to navigate to `ThirdScreen` and have the back stack be `[FirstScreen, ThirdScreen]`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `navigate()`, you add that new destination to the back stack. This means when you `navigate` to your `SecondScreen`, your back stack becomes:

```
FirstScreen -> SecondScreen
```

If you want to navigate to `ThirdScreen` and *also* remove `SecondScreen` from the back stack, that's exactly what `popUpTo` does as per the [Navigation Compose docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable):

```
navigator.navigate(ThirdScreenDestination) {
    popUpTo(SecondScreenDestination.route) {
        inclusive = true
    }
}
```

So you're doing two things as part of this single, atomic operation:

1. Popping every destination up to (that's the `popUpTo` part) and including (that's the `inclusive` part) `SecondScreen`. This is what removes `SecondScreen` from the back stack.
2. Navigating to `ThirdScreen`, which happens after the `popUpTo` completes, thus putting `ThirdScreen` on the top of the back stack.

Thus your final back stack is:

```
FirstScreen -> ThirdScreen
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution for a situation where user can navigate only using a button on your screen. But if he can navigate to ThirdScreen using a BottomNavigation or other way, what solution for this situations?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe you can update your question with more `[before back stack]` and `[after back stack]` examples of what you are trying to achieve. Even better would be to stop using fake names and actually explain your screens with real names that would help explain what you're trying to do in concrete terms.